# database triggers to populate current date on row insert and update not working

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers

### Functions-

**CREATE Function:**

```
-- Function: created_func()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION created_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.created_ts := current_timestamp;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION created_func()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**UPDATE Function:**

```
-- Function: updated_func()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updated_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.updated_ts := current_timestamp;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION updated_func()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

### Triggers-

**CREATE Trigger:**

```
-- Trigger: created_func on drcschema.dr_event

CREATE TRIGGER created_func
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON drcschema.dr_event
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE created_func();
```

**UPDATE Trigger:**

```
-- Trigger: update_func on drcschema.dr_event

CREATE TRIGGER update_func
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON drcschema.dr_event
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE updated_func();
```

### Columns-

**created_ts:**

-- Column: created_ts

```
ALTER TABLE drcschema.dr_event ADD COLUMN created_ts timestamp without time zone;
```

**updated_ts:**

-- Column: updated_ts

```
ALTER TABLE drcschema.dr_event ADD COLUMN updated_ts timestamp without time zone;
```

**DrEvent.hbm.xml:**

```
<property name="createdTs" type="timestamp" generated="insert">
   <column name="created_ts" length="29" />
</property>
<property name="updatedTs" type="timestamp" generated="always">
   <column name="updated_ts" length="29" />
</property>
```

Still I am not getting the date in `updated_ts` column after insert and update of row as seen below-

[image]

Comment: You can't change the column in an **AFTER** UPDATE trigger. You need a **BEFORE** UPDATE trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger because otherwise the changes will not persist to the table.

Other than that, with trigger functions that are so similar, it is good practice to combine them into one so that the "business logic" is in one place and thus easier to maintain:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_upd_func() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  -- Remember who changed the payroll when
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    NEW.created_ts := current_timestamp;
  ELSE
    NEW.updated_ts := current_timestamp;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_upd_tr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON drcschema.dr_event
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_upd_func();
```

Comment: ok it is working fine but please can you explain that when the row is first inserted then how `updated_ts` is also updated with the `current_timestamp` with your above logic ? I thought that `TG_OP = 'INSERT'` will only fill the `current_timestamp` for `created_ts ` and the else part will be discarded.

Comment: @MyGod: So you want to populate the `updated_ts` column at the time of first insert as well?

Comment: your above logic is doing the same. It is populating `updated_ts` column at the time of first insert as well. Although I want this to be populated as well but can't understand that how this logic is doing so.

Comment: That is not possible, at least not from the code in the trigger. Can you show the `INSERT` statement that you use to insert data into table `drcschema.dr_event`?