# How to set DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Postgres with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is a sister question to [How to set DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in mysql with sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992321/how-to-set-default-on-update-current-timestamp-in-mysql-with-sqlalchemy), but focused on Postgres instead of MySQL.

Say we want to create a table `users` with a column `datemodified` that updates by default to the current timestamp whenever a row is updated. The solution given in the sister PR for MySQL is:

```py
user = Table(
    "users",
    Metadata,
    Column(
        "datemodified",
        TIMESTAMP,
        server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
    ),
)
```

How can I get the same functionality with a Postgres backend?

Comment: There is no equivalent syntax in Postgres. You can only achieve that using a trigger

Comment: It is spelled out in the docs [SQL expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html?highlight=default#client-invoked-sql-expressions). See `onupdate`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver According to my tests simply passing `onupdate=func.utc_timestamp()` has no effect on a Postgres backend (it might in others)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is consistent with some of the reading I've done. I hope someone will answer with a sample implementation of a trigger for the example `users` table above

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147796/postgresql-trigger-update-timestamp-on-field-update) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864514/trigger-for-update-timestamp-field) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591691/creating-a-trigger-that-sets-a-timestamp-on-update) and [her€](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696888/create-auto-update-trigger-for-single-field-update-postgres) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231407/database-triggers-to-populate-current-date-on-row-insert-and-update-not-working)

Comment: That is because the function has to exist in the database and `utc_timestamp()` is not a Postgres function(remember SQLAlchemy is used against many databases). Try with `func.now()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Still doesn't work. Based on what I've read I tend to agree with a_horse_with_no_name that, for a Postgres backend, triggers are the way to go

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name appreciate the links, but none of them refers to a SQLAlchemy question. I understand how those references could point me to a solution, but for me the question remains open, e.g. what's the correct/pythonic way to do this with SQLAlchemy? Are there alternatives over `engine.execute(...)`? Can/should the code live with the `user` model in say `models.py`? How do I integrate this with a `create_all()` statement (or with alembic)?

Comment: Ah, the joys of obfuscation layers. I guess the "SQLAlchemy" way is whatever you need to run arbitrary SQL to create the function and the trigger definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I implemented this using triggers as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name in the comments. Full SQLAlchemy implementation and integration with Alembic follow.

#### SQLAlchemy implementation

```py
# models.py

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=sqlalchemy.func.now(), nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime)
```

```py
# your_application_code.py

import sqlalchemy as sa

create_refresh_updated_at_func = """
    CREATE FUNCTION {schema}.refresh_updated_at()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
    $func$
    BEGIN
       NEW.updated_at := now();
       RETURN NEW;
    END
    $func$;
    """

create_trigger = """
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_{table}_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON {schema}.{table}
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {schema}.refresh_updated_at();
    """

my_schema = "foo"
engine.execute(sa.text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))
engine.execute(sa.text(create_trigger.format(schema=my_schema, table="user")))
```

#### Integration with Alembic

In my case it was important to integrate the trigger creation with Alembic, and to add the trigger to *n* dimension tables (all of them having an `updated_at` column).

```py
# alembic/versions/your_version.py

import sqlalchemy as sa

create_refresh_updated_at_func = """
    CREATE FUNCTION {schema}.refresh_updated_at()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
    $func$
    BEGIN
       NEW.updated_at := now();
       RETURN NEW;
    END
    $func$;
    """

create_trigger = """
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_{table}_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON {schema}.{table}
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {schema}.refresh_updated_at();
    """

def upgrade():
    op.create_table(..., schema="foo")
    ...

    # Add updated_at triggers for all tables
    op.execute(sa.text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema="foo")))
    for table in MY_LIST_OF_TABLES:
        op.execute(sa.text(create_trigger.format(schema="foo", table=table)))

def downgrade():
    op.drop_table(..., schema="foo")
    ...

    op.execute(sa.text("DROP FUNCTION foo.refresh_updated_at() CASCADE"))
```

Comment: So we concluded that onupdate= doesn't work with Posgresql and the only solution is to create a trigger?